# subdomain support in meteor (like with slack - http://team.slack.com)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

subdomain support in meteor (like with slack - http://team.slack.com)

As in slack my app users can create their own subdomains (unique) and depending on the subdomain the data should be loaded, and around this the application would be proceeded. I can use something like http://slack.com?team=TeamName, but i think the subdomain would be much clean and better.

Any suggestions/pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: If you found the solution then can you share the full code with me. Please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/using-subdomain-as-parameter/167/9?u=sergiotapia).

---

Using a DNS wildcard to point *.example.com to my app server, I have this in the client code:

```
var hostnameArray = document.location.hostname.split( "." );

if ( hostnameArray[1] === "example" && hostnameArray[2] === "com" ) {
  var subdomain = hostnameArray[0];  
}

if ( subdomain ) {
  Meteor.call( "findTeamBySubdomain", subdomain, function (err, res) {
    var teamId = res;
    if ( teamId )
      Session.set( "teamId", teamId ); 
    }
  });
}

Tracker.autorun ( function () {
  Meteor.subscribe( "teamInfo", Session.get( "teamId" ) );
});
```

---

Make sure the currently signed in user has permission to view the `teamId` publication records. Anybody can tweak their session and say "I belong to this team." You need to make sure they are actually allowed.

Comment: any idea/suggestion how can I create these subdomains?