# Is there a way to auto generate sub domains in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to give the user a sub domain with their user name when they sign up.

Example is a user with josh sign up, I would like to give him a sub domain  josh.example.com where his profile is visible. Is this possible in meteor js?

Comment: Turns out my answer was incomplete. There is a better answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31488845/2805154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [solution](https://forums.meteor.com/t/using-subdomain-as-parameter/167/7) on the Meteor Forums. It involves using a wildcard dns entry:

Use a DNS wildcard to point *.example.com to your app server, then determine the hostname in your client code:

var hostnameArray = document.location.hostname.split( "." );
var hostname = hostnameArray[0];

if ( hostname ) {
  // here you can do whatever you need to do with the hostname
}